# $.extend with some condition in jquery

Tags: jquery

How to use `$.extend` with some condition?

```
obj=[{..}, {..}, {....}];

this.model.axes=[{..}, {..}, {...}];

$.extend(true, this.model.axes, obj);
```

`obj` is array of json object and same `this.model.axes`. I want to extend or merge the values from `obj` to `model.axes` but skip the first two indexes. That means no need to merge the values with `this.model.axes[0]` and `this.model.axes[1]` from `obj[0]` and `obj[1]`.

I want to merge `obj[0]` to `this.model.axes[2]` and `obj[1]` to `this.model.axes[3]` like that.

How can I skip first two json objects from `model.axes`?

thanks,

Siva

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is to concatenate the `obj` array to `this.model.axes` without the first two elements of `this.model.axes`, the following does it for you:

```
this.model.axes = this.model.axes.slice(2).concat(obj);
```

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zKT8p/2/))

If what you want is to replace the values of `this.model.axes` with the values of `obj` starting at the third element of `this.model.axes`, then use the following:

```
this.model.axes = this.model.axes.slice(0, 2).concat(obj);
```

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zKT8p/1/))

Finally, if what you want is to extend the objects in the arrays beginning with the third element of `this.model.axes` and continuing until the last element of `obj`, then you want the following:

```
for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i += 1) {
    if (obj[i]) {
        $.extend(true, this.model.axes[i + 2], obj[i]);
    }
}
```

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zKT8p/))

Comment: if any new json objects in obj whether it will merge in model.axes ?

Comment: i want just merge obj to this.model.axes but starting from 2 index (this.model.axes[2])

Comment: Do you mean you want to replace the old value of `this.model.axes[2]` with a new value, that of `obj[0]`, and so on?

Comment: Or do you want an array that is `[this.model.axes[0], this.model.axes[1], {this.model.axes[2], obj[0]}...]`?

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = [{id: 1},{id:2},{id:3}];
var arr2 = [{name: "joe"},{name:"john"},{name:"jack"},{name:"Jill"}];


function myMerge(arr1, arr2, start){
   var trimmed = arr2.slice(start);
    for(var i = 0; i < trimmed.length; i++){
        $.extend(true, trimmed[i], (arr[i])? arr[i]:{});
    }
    return [].concat(arr2.splice(0,start), trimmed);
}

console.log(myMerge(arr,arr2, 2));
//Outputs: [Object { name="joe"}, Object { name="john"}, Object { name="jack", id=1}, Object { name="Jill", id=2}]
```

**Working Example** http://jsfiddle.net/pf7yL/1/